# Opening keyboard in iOS cordova app when in split view (multitasking) shifts view port

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, cordova-ios, split-screen-multitasking

I'm running into an issue with a cordova iOS app on iPad that supports split view (multitasking).

When starting the app in split view everything works fine and the `document` has the correct size (`592 px`).
When focusing an input and the keyboard appears the `document` size changes to  the full size (`1194 px`).

Even after closing the keyboard the view is still the full size and stays that way until the app is closed.

Does anyone know if this is an issue with [`cordova-ios`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios), [`cordova-plugin-keyboard`](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard) or even `WKWebView`?

There is another [issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/417) open for `cordova-ios` that describes a similar issue with the keyboard messing up the view, but I'm not sure if they are related.

Comment: This looks like the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/56501953/754604. Does the solution there work for you?